# Integrating Moralis with Vite react

Tags: reactjs, npm, vite, yarn-v2, moralis

I am trying to integrate Moralis with my react vite application following the Moralis docs and after the installation i keep getting this error [image]

here is my main.jsx file

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import { MoralisProvider } from "react-moralis";

const APP_ID = APP_ID
const SERVER_URL = SERVER_URL;

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <MoralisProvider appId={APP_ID} serverUrl={SERVER_URL}>
      <App />
    </MoralisProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

I can't figure out what the issue is

Answer (score -1):

paste your app_id XXXXXXXX and your server url XXXXXX directly in main.jsx
remove {app_ID} {SERVER_URL}